Multiple Value Parameter Returns One Value Power BI Paginated Report
I'm trying to add a multiple value parameter to a paginated Power BI report in Power BI report builder. When selecting multiple values for the parameter, the report returns only the first row of data for the selected parameter.
My main query looks like this:  The query was made using the Query Designer feature and clicking "evaluate" to load the data results.
My parameter, "Client" has "Allow Multiple Values" checked and gets its values from a separate query with a list of all the clients. This query was built the same way, only pulling in the Client field.
In my main query, I added the parameter to the filters section of the dataset like this: 
The value is set =Parameters!Client.Value(0)
When I run this report, I'm returned only the first client in the selected list from the parameter. I have tried selecting all clients or just a couple. When I remove the parameter, I can see all rows for all clients. My visual is a matrix with grouping on the client.
I would like the parameter to return rows for all clients selected when I run the report.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

=Parameters!Client.Value(0) means use the value in index 0 (the first entry). Try looking at this article. https://prologika.com/ssrs-multivalue-parameters-in-dax/

I did figure out how to make this work.

Create new multiple select parameter
Open query designer and add desired columns
Add a new dimension to filter the data by the parameter
Dimension = table name; hierarchy = field to filter by; operator is =; filter expression = blank
Check first parameter box
Click enable multiple value parameter in top tool ribbon
Click OK to build the query with the new parameter

Query Designer add dimension to create parameter
In the parameter dataset properties, the parameter now appears to filter your dataset.
Dataset properties shows new parameter


In my main query, I added the parameter to the filters section of the dataset like this:

Filters on a dataset are applied after the dataset is retrieved.  You need to add the parameter to the dataset query itself.  The query designer can do this for you, or the details are explained here: Power BI Report Builder And RSCustomDaxFilter

Avoid the use of RSCustomDaxFilter function as you will not be able to use dax studio :}  Pass a Parameter to DAX Query Report Builder

Avoid the use of RSCustomDaxFilter function as you will not be able to use dax studio :}  Save the heartache and use my dax pattern for paginated reports posted in this thread.
Pass a Parameter to DAX Query Report Builder
